# WordPress Regenerate Thumbnails Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I created a C# desktop APP which creates products on my WP page using insert into commands.

I create wp_posts and wp_postmeta programmatically and I can see my product and the image which related to the product without any problem. However, I have problems with 'thumbnails'

I made a quick research and find that I can regenerate the thumbnails using [Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

I am wondering that do I have any chance to run this plugin using one of my php files? (Or call it directly from my C# desktop app using web request or something like that??)

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create API for your desktop app. when desktop app will send http request wordpress will create post and upload image with all necessary thumbnails.